# Scala Factorial method gives me wrong result, why?

Tags: scala

Hi i'm working on some examples on scala. There is a method called product which is multiplying all results of a given function in range of given numbers.

eg. product(somefunction: Int => Int) (lowerborder: Int, upperborder: Int)

The following multiplies all factorial results in the given range:

```
def product(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
   if (a > b) 1
   else f(a) * product(f)(a + 1, b)
}

def fact(x: Int, y: Int) = product(sFact)(x, y)

def sFact(c: Int): Int = if (c == 0) 1 else c * sFact(c - 1)

fact(3, 7)
```

Result of fact(3, 7) is (- wrong!):

```
 //> res0: Int = -1718845440
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is larger than 2<sup>31</sup>-1 ([`Int.MaxValue`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Int$@MaxValue:Int%282147483647%29)), so numeric overflow happens. You have to do all calculations modulo some value, or replace `Int` with `Long` or `BigInt` everywhere. But `Long` calculations will also start overflowing if arguments become bigger (`Long.MaxValue` is 2<sup>63</sup>-1 == 9223372036854775807).

Comment: This was the point, now it is working, i've forgotten these limitations ... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm looks good to me. This function does the same:

```
(3 to 7).map(sFact).fold(1)(_ * _)
```

As @Kolmar says, it is a problem with the types.